# Port forward fails on high data traffic, how can I fix it?

Tags: ssh, performance, port-forwarding

I wanted to test the bandwidth over port forwarding via `iperf`:

- On the first terminal: `ssh myraspberry -R 5001:localhost:5001 -L 5002:localhost:5001`
- On the second terminal: `iperf -s`
- On the third terminal: `iperf -c localhost -p 5002`

`iperf -s` listens `localhost:5001`, ssh port forward forwards `localhost:5001` to `RPi/localhost:5001`, and then forwards `RPi/localhost:5001` back to `localhost:5002` where `iperf -c localhost -p 5002` connects to.

In this setup, ssh connection fails when `iperf -c ...` starts running and advances to its second step of testing (which I assume involves some high data traffic).

How can I prevent such a disconnection by only slowing down the data transfer?